# Why is APIM only verifying my client certificate when it is added as both a CA Certificate and a Certificate

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm setting up Azure API Management to secure a Logic App with a certificate. I've added the following policy to the API:

```
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null || !context.Request.Certificate.Verify()  || context.Request.Certificate.NotAfter<DateTime.Now || !context.Deployment.Certificates.Any(c => c.Value.Thumbprint == context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint))">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate" />
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
```

When I add the self-signed certificate, I can only make a successful call to the API when the certificate is added to both the CA certificates and Certificates. Otherwise I get an invalid certificate warning (the one from my policy) in Postman

[image: screenshot of API Management service Certificates node]

**Question** I don't believe this is normal behaviour and am sure I have done something incorrect. How do I correctly add the certificate to APIM and ensure it is used correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to remove *context.Request.Certificate.Verify()* policy.

This policy tries to build an X509 chain and perform some validations. Without knowing the CA it is not possible.